# Yii2 clearfix.less not populating in production environment

Tags: css, yii2, assets, mismatch, clearfix

I designed a website using Yii2, and while I have done many, this problem only appears on one of them due to some reason that I cannot determine.

The views from dektrium\yii2-user extension show up fine on my development environment, but are messed up in production. When I analyse the rendered page from both using Chrome, I noticed the following css is not generated in the production environment...

```
//Pseudo ::before element
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-fluid:after, .row:before, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:before, .nav:after, .navbar:before, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:before, .pager:after, .panel-body:before, .panel-body:after, .modal-header:before, .modal-header:after, .modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

When I disable the 'display' property in my development, then both the environments match (messed up). I tried uploading all the files in the assets folder, but that didn't help. I am not sure what to do. I could manually add the css to my own css file, but that would not fix the root cause of this issue, and I'd like to do that as a last resort.

Comment: ¿Can't you add a CSS rule in your theme to override this?

Comment: Yes I can, but as I mentioned, I'd like this to be the last option. There is some root cause for this not working and I want to fix that.